# How do I correctly work with char pointer to array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to pick up my C++; I have basic understanding of pointers and references; but when it comes to char pointer to array, it seems nothing works for me.

I have a small piece of codes here (omitted include and namespace statements), I have included my questions as comments below:

I have gone through at least 5 other questions on SO to try to understand it; but those answers didn't the answer I expected and to the extent that could help understand the actual issue there.

Could you kindly explain the problems I commented below with a bit of depth from the surface (so please don't dive into it directly)?

```
int main(){

    // 1 this is a char pointer to a char;
    char * c = new char;
    *c ='A';
    cout << c << endl; // this gives me memory address;
    cout << *c << endl;// this gives me the value in the memory address;


    // 2 this is a char array initialised to value "world";
    char d[6] = "world";
    cout << d[0] << endl; // this gives me the first element of char array;

    // 3 this is char pointer to char array (or array of char pointers)?
    char * str = new char[6];
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){ // 
        str[i]=d[i];     // are we assigning the memory address (not value) of respective elements here? 
    }                   // can I just do: *str = "world"; what's the difference between initialising with value
                       // and declaring the pointer and then assign value?  

    char * strr = "morning";

    char b[6] = "hello";


    cout << b << endl;
    cout << (*str)[i] << endl; // why? error: subscripts requires array or pointer type
    cout << str[1] << endl;
    cout << (*strr)[1] << endl; // why? error: subscripts requires array or pointer type

}
```

Comment: Work through this, start with n equal to 0: `ptr[n] == *(ptr + n) == *(n + ptr) == n[ptr]`

Comment: @RichardCritten == n[ptr]? could you give me an example thanks! I got the first 3 that solved my problem in the for loop!

Comment: A pointer variable points to a single element, even if that element is in an array. `(*str)[i]` invokes *two* dereferences, which is one too many.

Comment: It's just the way builtin `operator[]` is defined: `x1[x2] == *(x1 + x2)` and then `x2[x1] == *(x2 + x1)` basic maths `x1 + x2 == x2 + x1`

Comment: @RichardCritten so basically for me is str[1] == *( str + 1 ) == *(1 + str ) == 1[str] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> // 1 this is a char pointer to a char;

Right.

> // 2 this is a char array initialised to value "world";

Right, "world\0" is created by the compiler and is put in the read-only memory area of the program. Note that this is called a string literal. Then the string is copied over to the `char` array `d`.

> // 3 this is char pointer to char array (or array of char pointers)?

That's a char pointer yes, a pointer to a single `char`.

> // are we assigning the memory address (not value) of respective
>   elements here?

No, you're assigning the values of the elements. This is allowed because `str[i]` is the same as `*(str + i)` so you can use the same "array style" access with the pointer `str`. You're looping over the individual `char`s you have allocated with `new` and are assigning them the value of the chars in the `char` array `d`.

> // why? error: subscripts requires array or pointer type

Because you already dereference `str` (which is pointing at the start of the 6 element `char` array) with `*` which gives you a `char`, then you try to use that `char` like an array with `[1]` which makes no sense. `*str` would give you 'w' (the first element). And `str[1]` would give you `*(str + 1)` which is 'o' (the second element), don't double up.

---

A small-big side note, string literals are of type `const char[]`, not `char[]`, they're placed in read only memory and thus they can not be altered by the program (don't write to them).

```
char * strr = "morning";
```

This is very very bad, it treats a `const char[]` as a `char[]`, this has been deprecated in the standard for a while now and according to the current standard this is even illegal, yet compilers still allow it for some reason.

Because compilers allow this you could get some nasty situations like trying to modify the string literal:

```
char * strr = "morning";
strr[0] = 'w'; // change to "worning"
```

This will attempt to write to read-only memory, which is undefined behaviour and will probably/hopefully get you a segmentation fault. Long story short, use the appropriate type to have the compiler stop you before the code reaches runtime:

```
const char * strr = "morning";
```

---

side side note : don't forget to `delete` anything you allocated with `new`.

Comment: Thanks Gill this is very helpful. in another answer I saw the answer said, for example, p points the array, but *p points to first element. in your answer it doesn't seem so though? I think you are saying char * str = new char[6], str points to a single char?

Comment: @stucash Yes, the first element, which is a single char.

Comment: `char * strr = "morning"; strr[0] = 'w';` ... [GCC warns](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xOAgYvzNUfrdjqBN) even w/o "-pedantic", MSVC never warns even with "/Wall /std:c++latest". Both produce programs that cause a segfault.

Comment: @Gill Bates thanks; could you have a look of this implementation? const char*(\*p)[3]=&a is it the same as const char* \*p[3]= &a ?